# Reading two lines at a time while using enumerate()

Tags: python, regex, enumerate

As far as I see it right now, the enumerate function is necessary for my script. But since it only reads the txt file line by line I am not able to capture my RegEx pattern all the time. I would like to be able to read two lines at a time while using enumerate. Is this possible?

```
import re
import itertools

a_list = []    

f = open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
txt = f.readlines()

for k, line in enumerate(txt):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
        a_list.append((k, line))
```

I have tried (and failed) to use islice() like so:

```
import re
import itertools

a_list = []

f = open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
txt = f.readlines()
**while True:
    next_two_lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 2))
    if not next_two_lines:
        break**

for k, line in enumerate(txt):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
        a_list.append((k, line))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
for k, line in enumerate(zip(txt[::2], txt[1::2])):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', "{} {}".format(line[0], line[1])):
        a_list.append((k, line))
```

That will iterate over tuples that each one of them contains two lines.